# bash: number from line into a variable

Tags: bash

i need the Number of a specific line set into variable.
In this case: There is a line in a generated document (rsync) like this:

*Number of files transferred: **23***

```
var1=`grep -E '\<Number of files transferred: [0-9]+\>' /path/to/document.txt`<br>
```

gets me the line.

```
echo $var1 | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

shows me the **23**.
I need a (good) way to get the Number in a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this really your question? http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @Bernhard I wish the OP could read and answer your comment!

Comment: I just read it. And i'am so glad to get a little bit more wisdom now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
number=$(echo $var1 | egrep -o "[0-9]+")
```

The variable `number` should now have the *output* of the command `echo $var1 | egrep -o "[0-9]+"`.

---

If your `grep` supports PCRE, you could say:

```
number=$(grep -oP '\bNumber of files transferred: \K[0-9]+\b' /path/to/document.txt)
```

Comment: The poster is already using command substitution, albeit a different form.

Comment: @wich The OP perhaps doesn't _know_ what is being used.  The link to the documentation is intended to make the OP be aware of that (and attempting to educate) rather than simply throwing up a solution.

Comment: Command Substitution is the best way i think. PCRE is not supported on OS X natively. Finally it is part of a Script on a FreeNas BU-Server to send a status-mail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just select a substring if you know the length of the prefix.

```
var1=${var1:29}
```

Or, have a different approach instead of the grep

```
var1=$(sed -n -e '/.*\<Number of files transferred: ([0-9]\+)\>.*/\1/p' < /path/to/document.txt)
```

Comment: The length of the prefix is not the same all times. I am not very familiar with sed now. But I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Three alternative approaches:

1. You can use the `${WORD##PATTERN}` parameter expansion feature in [`bash`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) to extract the number:

   ```
   RSYNC=/path/to/document.txt
   TRANSFERRED=$(grep -E '^Number of files transferred: [0-9]+$' -- "$RSYNC")
   FILE_COUNT=${TRANSFERRED##*: }
   ```
2. Use `$IFS` (the *input field separator*) together with the `read` command and a *here string*:

   ```
   IFS=: read _ FILE_COUNT <<<"$TRANSFERRED"
   ```
3. Use [`sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) instead of `grep`, [as suggested by wich in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676478/68063), but since OS X has a BSD-ish version of `sed`, you will need to write the command like this:

   ```
   COMMAND='s/^Number of files transferred: \([0-9]\{1,\}\)$/\1/p'
   FILE_COUNT=$(sed -n -e "$COMMAND" -- "$RSYNC")
   ```

But, I think an important question to ask is, why are you storing the output of `rsync` in a file? Do you really need to keep it? If not, then you could pipe the output of `rsync` into a subshell that does whatever processing you need to do. For example, you could do this kind of thing:

```
rsync --stats ... | {
    FILE_COUNT=unknown
    TOTAL_SIZE=unknown
    while IFS=: read KEY VALUE; do
        case "$KEY" in
            Number of files transferred) FILE_COUNT=$VALUE ;;
            Total file size) TOTAL_SIZE=$VALUE ;;
        esac
    done
    case "$FILE_COUNT" in
        1) echo "$FILE_COUNT file ($TOTAL_SIZE bytes) was transferred."
        *) echo "$FILE_COUNT files ($TOTAL_SIZE bytes) were transferred."
    esac
}
```

Comment: I will try it the next days this way. The script stop the databases, create a volume-shadow-copy, send a WOL to the FreeNas-Server and so on. The script write the outputs to a log file and finally send a status-mail. I wanted to extract the most important stats to the header.